# Manually inserted contentControls not found in Word

Tags: office-js

Article:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/word-add-ins-reference-overview

Issue:
Firstly, I added multiple ContentControls manually in Document.
Then, I want to list all ContentControls.
But, search no result.

Visual Studio 2017
Office 2016

Step1: F5 to Run in VS.

Step2: In Word, Select '**Develop**' menu -> '**Insert a plain text content control**'

Step3: In right task panel, click search button.

```
    var docControls = context.document.contentControls;


    docControls.load(["items"]); 

    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {

            console.log(docControls);

        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        })
```

[steps gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RidFc.gif)

[image: Code image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For future reference, screen shots are great but screen shots of code are extremely hard to work with. You should include the code directly in your question so others can quickly copy/paste your code to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only type of content control supported in Office.js is the rich text content control. All the other ones are not yet supported, they are in our backlog but do not have a specific ETA.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I can reproduce that Plain Text content controls are not seen. I will follow up with the engineers.

Comment: Thank you.  I answered by follows.